# Showing Video in react-native IOS Application

Tags: video, reactjs, react-native

New to react-native. Serving data via internal API. I'm attempting to render videos in the app. To do this, it seems that most people either use [react-native-video](https://github.com/brentvatne/react-native-video) (which is what I'm currently trying to do) or use the built-in WebView component.

I'm having trouble getting access to the component. I installed react-native-video and linked it via rnpm per the setup instructions. I included it in the project like several other apps I found that were using it did:

```
import Video from 'react-native-video';
```

When I try to use

```
<Video
  source={{uri: video.url}}
/>
```

I have seen a couple different errors in the iOS simulator, but currently seeing `Cannot read property 'Constants' of undefined`. When I remove the `<Video />` tag I don't get the error. Haven't been able to figure out what I'm doing wrong in terms of setup. So my questions are essentially (1) is this even how I should be trying to include video with react-native and (2) assuming that it is, what am I doing wrong.

Please let me know if additional information is needed. Very new to react-native.

UPDATE: solved error by uninstalling and reinstalling.

Comment: did you get react-native-video working on the simulator? or do you need to test it on the device itself?

Comment: Got it working. It works in simulator.

Comment: Can i get an example of your code @toddmetheny? I tried to get it to work on the index just to see whether it works but to no avail.

Comment: Sure--at this point we've added a lot of complexity to it. Did you try running their example in a new project?

Comment: I'm on my phone right now but I'll ping you tomorrow from my computer.

Comment: Yes i did. Maybe my rnpm doesn't work. Hell i don't know. If i can get just a simple example of running some videos on the index.ios.js would be good enough for me to start tinkering. Even getting that up was a chore.

Comment: If their example isn't working then it's probably not installed properly. Their example worked right off the bat for me. Does it show up in your Libraries list in Xcode? `RCTVideo.xcodeproj`

Comment: I could DM you ours...but it's no longer a simple example. It has a bunch of stuff at this point. More than the example they provide.

Comment: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video/issues/179

Does this issue affect you? I will check and see whether RCTVideo is in the xcode project. I need to add it manually i guess

Comment: Nope. Plays fine in simulator for me.

Comment: God damn, then please DM me the code if it's not that confidential for you or i can DM you my code for you to see and test whether it works on your side?

Comment: yeah--ours doesn't belong to me. belongs to my employer...is yours on github? I could take a look. @diehell

Comment: i'll put it up and forward you the link. Stay tune. Thank You Todd.

Answer (score 1):

> install this three command

1:- `react-native-element`

2:- `react-native-vector-icons`

3:- `react-native-video`

and after run:- `react-native link`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, TouchableOpacity, } from 'react-native';
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements';
import Video from 'react-native-video';
export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    rate: 1,
    volume: 1,
    muted: false,
    resizeMode: 'contain',
    duration: 0.0,
    currentTime: 0.0,
    paused: true,
  };

  video: Video;

  onLoad = (data) => {
    this.setState({ duration: data.duration });
  };

  onProgress = (data) => {
    this.setState({ currentTime: data.currentTime });
  };

  onEnd = () => {
    this.setState({ paused: true })
    this.video.seek(0)
  };

  onAudioBecomingNoisy = () => {
    this.setState({ paused: true })
  };

  onAudioFocusChanged = (event: { hasAudioFocus: boolean }) => {
    this.setState({ paused: !event.hasAudioFocus })
  };

  renderVideoView = () => {
    const { fullScreen } = styles;
    return (
      <Video
        ref={(ref: Video) => { this.video = ref }}
        source={require('Your Video Url OR Path Hear')}
        style={fullScreen}
        rate={this.state.rate}
        paused={this.state.paused}
        volume={this.state.volume}
        muted={this.state.muted}
        resizeMode={this.state.resizeMode}
        onLoad={this.onLoad}
        onProgress={this.onProgress}
        onEnd={this.onEnd}
        onAudioBecomingNoisy={this.onAudioBecomingNoisy}
        onAudioFocusChanged={this.onAudioFocusChanged}
        repeat={false}
      />
    )
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {this.renderVideoView()}
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({ paused: !this.state.paused })}>
          {
            this.state.paused == true ?
              <Icon name='caretright' type='antdesign' color='#09548c' /> :
              <Icon name='pause' type='Foundation' color='#09548c' />
          }
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  fullScreen: {
    width: '100%', height: 233,
  },
});
```